# Extract attribute

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I want to extract data from a [web site](https://voronezh.leroymerlin.ru/catalogue/meshki-stroitelnye/?display=90&sortby=1&page=) using VBA. I have managed to extract some part of the output, but is not a complete one. I want to select the attribute with value `data-division-id`:

```html
<div class="ui-product-card" comparison-checked="false"
shopping-list-checked="false" data-product-web-saleable="true"
data-product-url="/product/tryapka-dlya-pola-grifon-50h70-sm-93724162/"
data-product-category-id="meshki-stroitelnye-201709_Opus_Family" 
data-product-price="35.90" data-sub-category-id="10" data-category-id="40"
data-product-material="Хлопок" data-product-gamma="A" data-unit="NIU" 
data-division-id="11" data-source="Pim" data-product-color="белый" 
data-product-stock-value="11185" data-product-has-linked-how-tos="0"
data-product-location="SearchPage" data-product-id="93724162" 
data-product-dimension65="STD" data-product-weight="0.1" 
data-rel="js-cat-product-item" data-product-brand="Grifon" data-place="plp"
data-element-id="ui-product-card" data-ga-root="data-ga-root"
data-sub-division-id="1150" data-product-name="Тряпка для пола Grifon 50х70 см">
```

I can't seem to find the element and select him. I've tried a few approaches that i'm aware of, but my most recent attempts are below:

```
 Sub test()
    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim topic As HTMLHtmlElement
    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://voronezh.leroymerlin.ru/catalogue/meshki-stroitelnye/?display=90&sortby=1", False
         Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .readyState = 4
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    For Each topic In html.getElementsByClassName("ui-product-card")
        With topic.getElementsByClassName("product-name")
            If .Length Then x = x + 1: Cells(x, 2) = .item(0).innerText
        End With
        With topic.getElementsByClassName("price-section-inner")
            If .Length Then Cells(x, 3) = .item(0).innerText
        End With
        '??? With topic.getElementsByTagName("[data-category-id]") 
           '??? If .Length Then Cells(x, 1) = .item(0).innerText
        End With
    Next topic
End Sub
```

I need some assistance with this.
Thanks

Comment: Should this `html.getElementsByClassName("ui-product-card__info")` be `html.getElementsByClassName("ui-product-card")`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav,  Thanks, correct

Comment: No probs.  Glad to help

Comment: But still not working with `data-division-id`.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp  Something like so `Dim d As MSHTML.HTMLDivElement

d.getAttribute ("data-division-id")`  I can't do anything to fully test yet, I'll try later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use *Option Explicit* in the head of every code module and look at my comments:

```
Sub test()
    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim topic As HTMLHtmlElement
    Dim x As Long

    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://voronezh.leroymerlin.ru/catalogue/meshki-stroitelnye/?display=90&sortby=1", False
        .send 'You need this line
        'Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .readyState = 4 'This works only with Internet Explorer
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    For Each topic In html.getElementsByClassName("ui-product-card")
        With topic.getElementsByClassName("product-name")
            If .Length Then x = x + 1: Cells(x, 2) = .Item(0).innerText
        End With
        With topic.getElementsByClassName("price-section-inner")
            If .Length Then Cells(x, 3) = .Item(0).innerText
        End With

        'Get an attribute like this
        Cells(x, 1) = topic.getAttribute("data-division-id")
    Next topic
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, Zwenn